# IFF Statement - Informatica powerCenter

Tags: powerbi, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I've seen an IFF that I have to translate to Java, but I'm not sure what it does.
Is similar to:

```
        IFF(cod=199, mot <> 'A', null);
```

I have a table of records, in which they are going to pass a filter, one column is cod and another is mot.

The IFF is in a filter, if a cod is different from 199, is that record deleted because there is a null in the "else"?

In another language would it be equal to:?

```
if (code == 199) {
return mot != 'A'
} else {
return false??; or return null?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since IIF is in a filter, null condition is always false and will exclude the data from going ahead and excluded from that point.
And you can combine both condition into one -
if (code == 199 and mot != 'A') then true else false.
So, equivalent code can be -

```
if (code == 199 and mot != 'A') {
return true
} else {
return false}
```